# IIS6 MVC2 Server starts sending out 404 after a while

Tags: iis-6, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http-status-code-404, iis

I have a W2k3 server running IIS6 and MVC2 (.net 4).

Right after the iis starts, everything works ok, the site runs fine. Extensionless urls work ok.

After a certain period of time (maybe of inactivity) the server stops working and starts to send 404 errors to the client.

As soon as I restart de application pool, everithing goes back to normal and the site is up again. The thing is, I shouldn't be restarting the application pool every few hours.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Do you by chance have more than one .NET web app running in that application pool targeting different versions of the framework?  If so, create a new application pool so that you have different application pools for apps that target different versions of the framework.

Comment: Hmmm., the site was previously running version 3.5 of the framework. But right now it is the only site on the server, targetted for .net 4. I will try deleting both the app pool and the site and see if it works.